find_package with version major, minor, patch, tweak example in cmake
I have been going through find_package syntax and it says this about version here https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html :

A single version with the format major[.minor[.patch[.tweak]]], where each component is a numeric value.

I have a package like this "package/1.0.0/integer-id/"
Thus I want package_VERSION_MAJOR to be 1, package_VERSION_MINOR to be 0, package_VERSION_PATCH to be 0, and package_VERSION_TWEAK to be integer-id. How do I specify this in find_package?
For example I did this:
find_package(Package 1[.0[.0[.75670974]]] EXACT REQUIRED)

It gives me error:
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:25 (find_package):
  find_package called with invalid argument "1[.0[.0[.75670974]]]"

I could not get an example, so thought to ask the community

Square brackets is common syntax to denote optional parameter in the documentation. As a user, you don't need to type them. Correct: find_package(Package 1.0.0.75670974 EXACT REQUIRED)

But I still don't know how to get package_VERSION_MAJOR, package_VERSION_TWEAK variables

In which script do you want to obtain version variables? FindPackage.cmake? package-config.cmake?  package-config-version.cmake? These all different types of script in the sense of processing find_package request. And documentation describes them separately.

The square brackets in the docs mean that whatever is inside them is optional. You want this:
find_package(foo 1.2.3.4 EXACT REQUIRED)

Angle brackets in the docs are for "template"/placeholder names. So in <PackageName>_VERSION_MAJOR, <PackageName> refers to whatever you passed as the first argument to find_package. I.e. the variable in my above example would be foo_VERSION_MAJOR.
